# How can i create a constructor with generics with same class as argument

Tags: java, generics

I have a class Expression:

```
public class Expression < E extends Number, V extends Number >
{
   public Expression(E lV, OPERATION operation, V rV) {
   }

   public Expression(Expression< E, V > lE, OPERATION operation, Expression< E, V > rE) {
   }
}
```

Expression.java compile without errors.

This is my main class code.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
        // Line 1. 
    refactored.Expression< ?, ? > ex1 = new refactored.Expression< Double, Float >(10d, OPERATION.PLUS, 10f);

        // Line 2.
    refactored.Expression< ?, ? > ex2 = new refactored.Expression< Double, Float >(-3d, OPERATION.MUL, 1f);

        // Line 3.
    refactored.Expression< ?, ? > ex3 = new refactored.Expression< refactored.Expression< Double, Float >, refactored.Expression< Double, Float > >(ex1, OPERATION.MINUS, ex2);
}
```

The Line 3 doesn't compile, it says:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
The constructor Expression<Expression<Double,Float>,Expression<Double,Float>>(Expression<capture#1-of ?,capture#2-of ?>, OPERATION, Expression<capture#3-of ?,capture#4-of ?>) is undefined
Bound mismatch: The type Expression<Double,Float> is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter <E extends Number> of the type Expression<E,V>
Bound mismatch: The type Expression<Double,Float> is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter <V extends Number> of the type Expression<E,V>
```

What's wrong with it?

Comment: What do you don't understand in the error message ?

Comment: Why Line 3 doesn't compiling?

Comment: Did you bothered to read the error message ? It's really clear to understand what's the problem is...

Comment: It appears to be clear, but the question is WHY? I provided 2 constructors in my class, so the second constructor should fit forLine 3...no?

Comment: `new refactored.Expression< refactored.Expression< Double, Float >, refactored.Expression< Double, Float > >` : `Expression` doesn't extend the `Number` class as it should be according to the class declaration ( `Expression < E extends Number, V extends Number >` ). It's why it doesn't work.

Comment: OK thanks, it proves it do not understand yet how generics works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expression does not extend number so it is not a legal type parameter.

**edit - to address the comment**
I am not sure why you need the generic solution for this...
you can have something like

```
interface Expression {
  Number compute();
}

class AtomicExpression implements Expression {
  private final Number number;
  AtomicExpression(Number number) {
    this.number = number;
  }
  public Number compute() {
    return number;
  }
}

class BinaryExpression implements Expression {
  private final Expression expr1;
  private final Expression expr2;
  private final Operator op;
  AtomicExpression(Expression expr1, Expression expr1. Operator op) {
    this.expr1 = expr1;
    this.expr2 = expr2;
    this.op = op;
  }
  public Number compute() {
    return op(expr1.compute(), expr2.compute());
  }
}
```

Comment: So, how could i create a instance of Expression which takes an Expression as argument into constructor?

Comment: it depends on what you want to achieve. If all of your atomic expressions will always have the same types you can go with anubhava suggestion, otherwise you'll probably need a more complex type hierarchy.

Comment: I need to create a class Expression which can compute a simple mathematical expression like: (a + b) or a Expression which can compute 2 Expressions like: (b + c) * (a + b).

Answer (score 0):

refactored.Expression< ?, ? > ex3 = new refactored.Expression <
Double, Float>(ex1, OPERATION.MINUS, ex2);

This should work.

Comment: It give this error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 The constructor Expression<Double,Float>(Expression<capture#1-of ?,capture#2-of ?>, OPERATION, Expression<capture#3-of ?,capture#4-of ?>) is undefined

 at original.Main.main(Main.java:17)

Answer (score 0):

It is obvious from errors you're getting that `Expression<?, ?>` is not a subclass of Number. If you really want to accept Expression in your constructor then you need to remove the **upper bonded parameter** (Number) from generics.

Something like this should work for you:

```
public class Expression <E, V> {
    public Expression(E lV, OPERATION operation, V rV) {}
    public Expression(Expression< E, V > lE, OPERATION operation, Expression< E, V > rE) {}
}
```

**Update:** This should work then:

```
Expression< Double, Float > ex1 = new Expression< Double, Float >(10d, OPERATION.PLUS, 10f);

Expression< Double, Float > ex2 = new Expression< Double, Float >(-3d, OPERATION.MUL, 1f);

Expression< ?, ? > ex3 = new Expression
 < Expression< Double, Float >, Expression< Double, Float > >(ex1, OPERATION.MINUS, ex2);
```

Comment: It giving this Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 The constructor Expression<Expression<Double,Float>,Expression<Double,Float>>(Expression<capture#1-of ?,capture#2-of ?>, OPERATION, Expression<capture#3-of ?,capture#4-of ?>) is undefined

 at original.Main.main(Main.java:17)`

Comment: Use `Expression< Double, Float > ex1` and `Expression< Double, Float > ex2`

Comment: That's i made before open current post(see my original question).

Comment: I have edited answer to help you, see if this works for you. I don't know how can see your original question.

Comment: where is the difference between your last proposition and my original post? Anyway i've tried it and it doesn't compiling.

Comment: DIFFERENCE is `refactored.Expression< ?, ? > ex1` vs **`refactored.Expression< Double, Float > ex1`** i.e. using concrete parameters instead of wildcards.